# Laravel htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel, twitch

I'm trying to use https://github.com/skmetaly/laravel-twitch-restful-api package to get twitch integration to my website.

That's the error that i get.

```
ErrorException in helpers.php line 469:
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/msvixen/resources/views/twitch.blade.php)
```

My controller
        $code = Input::get('code');

```
    if ($code !== null)
    {
        $token = TwitchApi::requestToken($code);
    } else
    {
        $token = null;
    }

    $data = TwitchApi::streamsFollowed($token);

    return view('twitch', ['token' => $token, 'data' => $data]);
```

my view

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
    <h1>Twitch.TV</h1>
    {{ $token }}

    {{ $data }}
@endsection
```

After using `dd()`

```
array:9 [▼
  0 => array:11 [▼
    "_id" => 17733016640
    "game" => "World of Warcraft"
    "viewers" => 15551
    "created_at" => "2015-11-15T22:27:13Z"
    "video_height" => 1080
    "average_fps" => 60.2769481401
    "delay" => 0
    "is_playlist" => false
    "_links" => array:1 [▶]
    "preview" => array:4 [▶]
    "channel" => array:22 [▶]
  ]
  1 => array:11 [▶]
  2 => array:11 [▶]
  3 => array:11 [▶]
  4 => array:11 [▶]
  5 => array:11 [▶]
  6 => array:11 [▶]
  7 => array:11 [▶]
  8 => array:11 [▶]
]
```

so it works, but when i try to display data - its back to the `htmlentities()` error

Comment: Either `$token` or `$data` is an array rather than a string. Use `dd()` or similar to debug the variables. `{{ $token }}` causes Blade to run `htmlentities($token)` behind the scenes which then fails because of the above

Comment: Given that the method used to set `$data` is entitled `streamsFollowed()` I'd expect that to return an array given it's use of the plural streams.

Comment: i checked with `dd()` and `$data` is an array, i tried displaying it with `@foreach` with `$data as $stream` and then using `{{ $stream->streams }}` but that failed. Do you know how to correctly display this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `$data` is returned as an array.

When `TwitchApi::streamsFollowed($token);` is called, the Facade calls the method in `Skmetaly\TwitchApi\Services\TwitchApiService`.

This in turn creates an instance of `Skmetaly\TwitchApi\API\Users` and calls the `streamsFollowed()` method there.

This method makes a call to [`/streams/followed`](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/users.md#get-streamsfollowed) which returns a data set such as the example below. It's automatically converted to an array rather than JSON using the Guzzle HTTP Client's [`json()` method](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/response.html#json-responses).

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/followed?limit=25&offset=0",
    "next": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/followed?limit=25&offset=25"
  },
  "_total": 123,
  "streams": [...]
}
```

In order to display the streams you'd need to iterate over the streams array within `$data`.

If you were to modify your controller slightly

```
return view('twitch', ['token' => $token, 'streams' => $data->streams]);
```

You'd then be able to iterate over the streams in your view.

```
@foreach($streams as $stream)
    {{ $stream }}
@endforeach
```

**Update:** You'll notice that each stream is also an array. What this means is you need to choose which of the keys in each array you'd like to display. Let's assume that inside one of the streams there is a key called `broadcaster` which contains a string; you could modify the above as follows.

```
@foreach($streams as $stream)
    {{ $stream['broadcaster'] }}
@endforeach
```

Having now read the [streams example response documentation](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v2_resources/streams.md#example-response) it would appear that the contents of a stream varies depending on whether or not the stream is online. NB: This is assuming the data structure is the same as you've not posted the contents of a stream in your question.

This means that offline, `{{ $stream['broadcaster'] }}` would work, but when online it wouldn't and you'd get the same error. What you'll likely need to do is use an `@if @else` block in your `@foreach` to determine if the stream is `null` before trying to echo part of the information.

You could also filter the offline streams in the controller by removing null values from data.

Comment: Can you update your question and paste the output of `dd($data)` please?

Comment: `dd()` works, the result is there, but displaying is breaking things up

Comment: `return view('twitch', ['token' => $token, 'streams' => $data->streams]);` gives and other error now -> `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Data is an array. I'd guessed it was an object before you'd posted the structure. You should get used to using `dd()` to determine the structure of the data you're trying to use. It'll help you fix things like that quickly and easily. Change `$data->streams` to `$data['streams']`